# Is this continuously-generated app_offline.htm file going to plague or irritate users?

Tags: asp.net, html, visual-studio, razor, app-offline.htm

While testing my Razor/asp.net web site, I continually find a file named "app_offline.htm" in my Recycle Bin. Is this something that will plague the poor unsuspecting visitor to my site?

Comment: Try it from another computer! That way you can easily determine if it's generated by the server side or client side of the application. Of course, a VM will do just fine.

Comment: Something is generate it for probably make an update of your page, or something similar, after the update is simple delete it.

Answer (score 1):

It won't be the case while you publish your site. Reason is:
`SQL Server 2005 express edition does not support multiple processes. Only single process can access database at a time. So when a database is accessed through visual studio, ASP.net runtime cannot access the database. This will result into the internal server error. To prevent this, VS 2005 places app_offline.htm file in the application's root directory. The file contain above message. This causes ASP.net to put the application in offline mode.`

source: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21319/Putting-ASP-net-Application-In-Offline-Mode-Using

Comment: Strange, as I'm not using SQL Server express of any year or edition in this site.

Comment: app_offline.htm is a method that is used by VS2005 to keep your application safe.

Comment: Okay, but I'm not using VS2005; This is a web site built with VS2012 that does not use any database features.